# convert values in a pandas df column using another df's value depending on matching strings

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having difficulties with the following:

I have a first Pandas df that is built in the following manner:

```
index|date|price
0    |2011|1000
1    |2011|1100
2    |2012|1200
3    |2013|1300
```

The date values are simple strings.

Another df has the inflation rates (grossly calculated) for each year:

```
date |rate
2011 |0.1 
2012 |0.2 
2013 |0.3
```

My aim is to be able to use this second dataset to convert the price values in the first. (divide price value by the inflation rate using appropriate year's value)

end result should be something like this:

```
index|date|price
0    |2011|10000
1    |2011|11000
2    |2012|6000
3    |2013|4333
```

Any help greatly appreciated. Probably the solution is already out there but I struggled formulating the google query to get to it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do it this way:

```
In [90]: df1['price'] /= df1['date'].map(df2.set_index('date')['rate'])

In [91]: df1
Out[91]:
   index  date         price
0      0  2011  10000.000000
1      1  2011  11000.000000
2      2  2012   6000.000000
3      3  2013   4333.333333
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to highlight the use of `axis` and `level` in [**`pd.DataFrame.div`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html)

```
df1.set_index(
    'date', append=True
).div(
    df2.set_index('date').rate, axis=0, level=1
).reset_index(1)

       date         price
index                    
0      2011  10000.000000
1      2011  11000.000000
2      2012   6000.000000
3      2013   4333.333333
```

---

```
df1.set_index('date', append=True)

            price
index date       
0     2011   1000
1     2011   1100
2     2012   1200
3     2013   1300
```

And

```
df2.set_index('date').rate

date
2011    0.1
2012    0.2
2013    0.3
Name: rate, dtype: float64
```

We can see that level 1 of the modified `df1` dataframe's index is the same `'data'` values as in the index of modified `df2`.  We can target that alignment with the `axis` and `level` parameters.

That said, for this specific problem... No way I don't copy @MaxU!